# Using group by with date

Tags: sql

I have a table containing the following columns:

```
stats_date (YYYY-MM-DD)
registered (INT)
opened_form (INT)
```

Compose a query that will return the total `registered`, and `opened_form` by month for the last 3 months. Also a calculated column called `conversion_rate` which is the `registered` column divided by the `opened_form`.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results would clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for aggregation?  Date/time functions differ significantly among databases, but the idea is:

```
select year(stats_date), month(stats_date),
       sum(registered), sum(opened_form),
       sum(registered) * 1.0 / sum(opened_form) as ratio
from t
group by year(stats_date), month(stats_date)
order by min(stats_date);
```

Of course, your database might have a different way of extracting the year and month from a date.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the [ANSI SQL](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eshadow/sql/sql1992.txt) at page 187 to understand how agregation works. To know how to group your column by Month you need to check the documentation of your db, usually is `MONTH(COLUMN_NAME)`.